# Can't get map object from PySpark with SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've built a code that reads a parquet file, queries it by SQL query - while I'm using a udf (udf gets a list object and returns a dictionary object), and then saves it as parquet as well.

As output I want to get a Map type, in the column I'm getting back from the udf (the dictionary).

But I get a String type.

UDF:

```
def udf_count_frequencies(elements):
    if not elements:
        return None

    counter = Counter()
    for e in elements:
        e = unicode(e).encode('utf-8').strip()
        counter[e] += 1

    return dict(counter)
```

SQL:

```sql
select user_id, count_frequencies(collect_list(group))
from user_likes
group by 1
```

How can I query the data, and get back a response that sets the column as map while I'm saving it - and does not transform it into string?

Comment: Can you paste your code here ?

Comment: @howie - Hey, I've edited my question with the code

Comment: Do you want count_frequencies(collect_list(group)) return as map type ?
Can you print your dataframe schema ?

Comment: @howie - My dataframe schema is 2 columns - user_id string, group string - I want to get back a map of: group --> # of appearances.

Comment: group by user_id  or group by 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to give your udf map type ?

```
udf_flatten_counter = udf(
    lambda x: dict(Counter(x)),
    MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
```